# Unable to connect to ntfy server behind apache2 proxy

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy

I installed ntfy on LMDE 6 and can connect and publish using localhost:port. In apache2 I set up a virtual host as a SSL reverse proxy. I am not able to connect to ntfy using this reverse proxy.

I configured ntfy like so:

```
base-url: "http://my.domain.tld"
listen-http: ":2586"
cache-file: "/var/cache/ntfy/cache.db"
behind-proxy: true
attachment-cache-dir: "/var/cache/ntfy/attachments"
attachment-total-size-limit: "5G"
attachment-file-size-limit: "15M"
attachment-expiry-duration: "3h"
```

My systemd unit file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=ntfy server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ntfy
Group=ntfy
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ntfy serve --no-log-dates
ExecReload=/bin/kill --signal HUP $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
LimitNOFILE=10000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As aspected, testing the ntfy server:

```
curl -d "Test message" 127.0.0.1:2586/test
```

Returns:

```
{"id":"e90syHWIVPTq","time":1706267958,"expires":1706311158,"event":"message","topic":"test","message":"Test message"}
```

I enabled modules *proxy* and *proxy_http* and set up virtual host in apache2 (fake url):

```
<VirtualHost *:11705>
    ServerName my.domain.tld

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.tld/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.tld/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    # Proxy connections to ntfy (requires "a2enmod proxy proxy_http")
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2586/ upgrade=websocket
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2586/

    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
    SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1

    # Higher than the max message size of 4096 bytes 
    LimitRequestBody 102400

</VirtualHost>
```

Trying to connect via the proxy:

```
curl -d "Test message" https://my.domain.tld:11705/test
```

Returns:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my.domain.tld port 11705 after 26 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved: In virtual host add line: Listen 11705